# error when developing with android on 64 bit linux

Tags: android

Every time that I try to develop with my 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04, I keep getting this error. I installed Java 7 Update 5, downloaded and set up the Android Development Kit, downloaded and extracted Eclipse, installed the Android Development Tools for Eclipse, pointed Eclipse to the Android SDK directory, and finally try to run one of my projects, I get an error like so:

/home/user/Downloads/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

What do I need to install to fix this error?

Thanks,

Jeremy

Comment: Use Java 6. Java 7 isn't supported for Android SDK.